# How to do action while key hold?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm doing an autoclicker and I have a problem: I want the program to execute the Click() method while I hold the C key.

I tried this. once I press a key and my code stuck's an infinite loop. I saw a similar problem on StackOverflow but it didn't work for me.
Here is my code:

```
private static bool IsHolded = false;
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Keys key = e.KeyData;
    if (key == Keys.C)
    {
        IsHolded = true;
        while (IsHolded)
        {
            Click();
        }
    }
}

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    IsHolded = false;
}
```

Comment: You cannot use a while loop (almost anywhere in this Platform). Use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead. `SystemInformation.KeyboardSpeed` tells you what to set the Timer's Interval to

Comment: "I want the program to execute the Click() method while I hold the C key." This requirement is unclear. Are you saying that while the C key is held down you want the Click() method called repeatedly? How many times per second? What does the Click() method do?

Comment: @JohnWu I want the method to run as long as I hold down the button After the button is released, the click method will stop executing.

Comment: @HarabeKowalski I still don't know what you mean. A method runs until it is done. You can't really make it run longer unless you change the method. So I ask again, what does the Click() method do?

Comment: @JohnWu Click() emulates left button click.I want to do Click() until I release key.

Comment: @HarabeKowalski A mouse click consists of a mouse down and a mouse up event. You can't click "continuously." You can click *repeatedly*, which is different. Or do you mean that when you press and hold C it emulates a mouse down event, and releasing the C emulates a mouse up event? You need to be specific because the implementation of these requirements would be very different.

Comment: No. When i C key down  it starts    Doing click() method in loop. When C key up it stop doing this method method in loop.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your concept you can implement it in different ways. You can run the inner code in another thread and handle the KeyUp events via CancellationToken. Here is an implementation:

```
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Keys key = e.KeyData;
        if (key == Keys.C)
        {
            IsHolded = true;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(DoSomeWork), cts.Token);
        }
    }
    private void DoSomeWork(object obj)
    {
        CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken)obj;

        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            //Do Some Work
        }
    }
    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        IsHolded = false;
    }
```

There is no need to initialize IsHolded variable unless you want to use it to prevent multiple executions when you hold the 'c' key. For this you should check the IsHolded value within the IF statements in the KeyPress method:

if (key == Keys.C && !IsHolded)

Remember, if you cancel the CancellationTokenSource, it remains in the cancel state and doesn't work next time when you press the 'c' key. So, if you want to handle it you should Dispose and reinitialize the old 'ctx' in the KeyUp method. Here are two articles about CancelationToken.

[Cancellation in Managed Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads)
and
[Register callbacks for cancellation requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-register-callbacks-for-cancellation-requests)